# Laravel : Eloquent query for self JOIN

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a categories table where categories have a parent mentioned within same table as in below screenshot

[image]

I want to implement self join in Laravel using Eloquent where parent category is mentioned in  a  saperate col:

Raw Sql Query:

```
DB::select("SELECT  c.id, c.name, parents.name AS `Parent Category Name`
FROM  product_categories AS c
LEFT  JOIN  product_categories AS parents ON parents.id = c.parent
ORDER BY   c.name ASC");
```

which gives me following result :

```
array:3 [
  0 => {#1146 
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "category 1"
    +"Parent Category Name": "category 2"
  }
  1 => {#673 
    +"id": 2
    +"name": "category 2"
    +"Parent Category Name": null
  }
  2 => {#1079
    +"id": 3
    +"name": "category 3"
    +"Parent Category Name": null
  }
]
```

i want to achieve the same using Laravel Eloquent and then loop in my view , can someone please help me i have tried multiple variations found from my searches which did not work

Comment: Did you create your models with relationships and everything... ?

Comment: i simply created model using make: model command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
$result = ProductCategorie::leftJoin('product_categories as parents', 'parents.id', '=', 'product_categories.parent')
         ->select('product_categories.id', 'product_categories.name', 'parents.name as ParentCategoryName')
         ->get();
```

Comment: yes that worked  . Thanks for your response. One thing is it also achievable using relationships ? if you could give me a direction not the full query I would do some search in general on that . Thanks